# Set value to environment variable and use in conditional plugin in Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I have a small batch code which prints the License information of a executable to a file `version.txt` and does a check whether the License is `Product is licensed to MyOrg`. If they are not equal, I explicitly throw `exit 1` and fail the build, else echo the value of the variable. Below is the working code.

```
@echo off
product_executable --version 1>version.txt 2>&1
FOR /F "SKIP=1 TOKENS=*" %%L IN (version.txt) DO set checkstr=%%L
del /q /f version.txt
if NOT "%checkstr%"=="Product is licensed to MyOrg" ( EXIT 1 ) else ( ECHO %checkstr% )
```

But what I need is, instead of saving the variable to the file and reading lines from it and deleting the file, I want to save it to a environment variable say `license_info` and access it in the [Conditional Build Step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin like `${license_info}`. But I am unable to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done in the past is use the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), and write the `key=value` information to [a `.properites` formatted file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties).

A java .properties file is basically just

```
key_1=value_1
key_2=value_2
license_info=someinterestinglicenseinfo
key_n=value_n
```

String values do not need quotes.

Then, using the plugin, you can then reference that file, perhaps written to your `${WORKSPACE}`, and have access to those environment variables in forms a la `${license_info}`

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any direct way to create environment variables in a shell script (or windows batch script) and have it available in a later build step. The only way to get around it, is to write the info out in a properties file and have the next build step read the properties file. As smlstvnh you need to use the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to read the properties file. I used this cumbersome method in some of my builds.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this in batch which removes the need to write the text file...

```
@echo off
FOR /F "SKIP=1 TOKENS=*" %%L IN ('product_executable --version') DO set checkstr=%%L
if NOT "%checkstr%"=="Product is licensed to MyOrg" ( EXIT 1 ) else ( ECHO %checkstr% )
```

But this will not help if you are trying to remove the batch file completely.

Comment: checkstr is empty when i execute like this

Comment: Try `FOR /F %%L IN ('product_executable --version') DO echo %%L` to see what you need to put in the options for SKIP and TOKENS.  Use `FOR /?` for help with tokens and the other options.